# nodemon for my app.js isn't refreshing on reload

Tags: javascript, node.js

Really beginner question I think.. I've been running nodemon app.js tutorial and starts correctly (version is 2.0.12, latest). I set up express to run as well but every time i attempt to update any of my ejs templates.. it won't reload to see the changes.. I have to manually reload in my browser. Is there something with my routes? Routes and such show up fine but I can't get the live reload to work.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Campground = require('./models/campground')

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/yelp-camp', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})

const db = mongoose.connection
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"))
db.once("open", ()=>{
    console.log("Database connected")
})

// App Logic
app.engine('ejs', ejsMate)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

// Forms POST object
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('home')
})

//Load all Campgrounds into ejs file
app.get('/campgrounds', async (req, res) => {
const campgrounds = await Campground.find()
    res.render('campgrounds/index', { campgrounds })
})

// Create & Read

app.get('/campgrounds/new', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('campgrounds/new')
})

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Boiler Plate</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">YelpCamp</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="/campgrounds">Campgrounds</a>
              <a class="nav-link" href="/campgrounds/new">New Campground</a>
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <main class="container">
        <%- body %>
    </main>
    

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this the full code?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a script in package.json file.

```
"start": "nodemon server.js -e ejs,js,css,html,jpg,png,scss"
```

You can give whatever name instead of start, after that you write Nodemon then your main server file name, -e is used to tell Nodemon what file type Nodemon have to watch for changes. Let's say you want Nodemon to watch for HTML file types and any time you make changes in HTML files of your server directory Nodemon should restart the server.

Comment: almost!!! after every save in my EJS template.. i see the database refresh in my console BUT the content on the page doesn't refresh.. thats progress..wondering why.. =[

Comment: when data has come you need to render data then it will update at EJS template

For example
  res.render('pages/index', {
    mascots: mascots,
    tagline: tagline
  });